# The order of running subprocess in multiprocess module

Tags: python, multiprocessing

To start multiprocess with for loop.

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Process

def run_proc(name):
    print('child process %s (%s) running ...' %(name,os.getpid()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('parent process %s.' %os.getppid())
    for i in range(5):
        p = Process(target=run_proc,args=(str(i),))
        print('process will start'+str(i))
        p.start()
    p.join()
    print('process is end')
```

I got the result.

```
parent process 6497.  
process will start  
process will start  
child process 0 (6984) running ...  
process will start  
process will start  
process will start  
child process 2 (6986) running ...  
child process 1 (6985) running ...  
child process 3 (6987) running ...  
child process 4 (6988) running ...  
process is end
```

Why the subprocess created early execute  later?
Why can't get the following outcome?

```
parent process 6497.  
process will start  
process will start  
child process 0 (6984) running ...  
process will start  
process will start  
process will start  
child process 1 (6986) running ...  
child process 2 (6985) running ...  
child process 3 (6987) running ...  
child process 4 (6988) running ...  
process is end
```

What Jean-François Fabre says is about how to create the following result:

```
parent process 6497.
process will start
child process 0 (9639) running ...
process will start
child process 1 (9640) running ...
process will start
child process 2 (9641) running ...
process will start
child process 3 (9643) running ...
process will start
child process 4 (9644) running ...
process is end
```

I can get it just to change p.join  in for loop such as below:

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Process

def run_proc(name):
    print('child process %s (%s) running ...' %(name,os.getpid()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('parent process %s.' %os.getppid())
    for i in range(5):
        p = Process(target=run_proc,args=(str(i),))
        print('process will start'+str(i))
        p.start()
        p.join()
    print('process is end')
```

What I want to know is why my code result in the following output

```
parent process 6497.  
process will start  
process will start  
child process 0 (6984) running ...  
process will start  
process will start  
process will start  
child process 2 (6986) running ...  
child process 1 (6985) running ...  
child process 3 (6987) running ...  
child process 4 (6988) running ...  
process is end
```

instead of:

```
parent process 6497.  
process will start  
process will start  
child process 0 (6984) running ...  
process will start  
process will start  
process will start  
child process 1 (6986) running ...  
child process 2 (6985) running ...  
child process 3 (6987) running ...  
child process 4 (6988) running ...  
process is end
```

It is a different issue.

Comment: Please don't post *pictures* of text. Just post the text itself.

Comment: you have a race condition. Why don't you add a small delay when creating the processes?

Comment: If you want to do them in order don't use `multiprocessing`. If you don't care the order and you want them to be run in parallel then use `multiprocessing` that delegates this part to the OS.

Comment: @Adirio if you want the _results_ to be yielded in order you can use `map` from multiprocessing.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yeah, there are multiple way of handling the order of the results, but you do not control the order of execution. If the order of execution matters, and with `print`s it does as the terminal is not thread-safe, then you have to re-visit the design decission of using multiprocessing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you have a [*race condition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) between the main process which creates the processes, and the processes which try to start (and the sub-processes themselves).

As soon as you issue the `p.start()` command from the main process, the child process *can* run (and print). But the main process is also working hard to create the *next* child process. Who is going to print the next line first? hard to know. If the main process succeeds in creating the next child process, now the race condition is between both children: what you're experiencing.

The processes may run in parallel, but they're still have synchronization points when calling the operating system. Whoever reaches the OS first gets served first (example: print to the console).

Of course, putting the `p.join()` *within* the loop restores the order, it also cancels the effect of the multiprocessing since *the main process waits until child process has ended before creating another*.

It generally doesn't matter, since you're doing some parallel tasks.

I would first create the processes in a list comprehension, then loop to start them, with a small delay to make sure that the process starts & prints before the next process is created.

```
process_list = [Process(target=run_proc,args=(str(i),)) for i in range(5)]
for i,p in enumerate(process_list):
    print('process {} will start'.format(i))
    p.start()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

When the main process waits a little while, this gives breathing space to the child process to start & print.

Also note that your last `p.join()` is only joining the last process of the loop, it should be (now using our brand new `process_list`):

```
for p in process_list:
    p.join()
```

Starting/ending in order isn't really important in most cases. You can pre-compute all the ordering information in the main process (like you did by assigning increasing numbers to the process names).

Note that the classic problem may be not to ensure that the processes start sequentially, but that the result they yield can be matched with the input you provided (pass the processes a list of inputs, and they yield a list of outputs, so in the end you know which input provided which output).

In that case, look for `multiprocessing.pool` and the `map` function ([Python multiprocessing.pool sequential run of processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27282538/python-multiprocessing-pool-sequential-run-of-processes))

Comment: In your code it's print('process will start') can run instead of print('process will start'+str(i))!

Comment: How to explain the order in my post ?

Comment: I have edited to add more information. It's basically a race condition.

Comment: There are two kinds of race condition : one is between the main process which creates the processes and its children, and  other one is the race condition  between both children  processes. Is that so?

Comment: when both subprocesses are created, anything goes to know which is going to call 'print' first.